# \TeX and \LaTeX differently expl3-x-written (exhaustive expansion) to an auxiliary file

Tags: expansion, expl3, auxiliary-files

As pointed out by the following MCE, `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` are `expl3`-written to an auxiliary file:

- **the same way** when **no manipulation** is involved (`\iow_now:Nn`) (but that is useless for my real use case):

  ```
  \LaTeX {}
  \TeX {}
  ```
- **differently** when **exhaustive expansion** is involved (`\iow_now:Nx`):

  ```
  \protect \LaTeX  {}
  T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@{}
  ```

Why this difference and how to get `\protect \TeX  {}` instead of `T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@{}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_output_stream

\iow_open:Nn \g_output_stream { \c_sys_jobname_str.sbj }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \TeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:V\LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:V\TeX{} }
\iow_close:N \g_output_stream

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You surely don't want `\exp_not:V`, but rather `\exp_not:N`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we do `\show\TeX`, the result is

```
\TeX=macro:
->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@.
```

On the other hand, the result of `\show\LaTeX` is

```
   > \LaTeX=macro:
   ->\protect \LaTeX  .
```

Now `\LaTeX` is defined in `latex.ltx` using `\DeclareRobustCommand`, and as @egreg has pointed out, `\MakeRobust` can protect an existing macro in the same way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\MakeRobust{\TeX}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_output_stream

\iow_open:Nn \g_output_stream { \c_sys_jobname_str.sbj }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \TeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:V\LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:V\TeX{} }
\iow_close:N \g_output_stream

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\MakeRobust{\TeX}` is the correct way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Too bad `\TeX` and friends are not defined in `latex.ltx` using `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want `\exp_not:V`, but rather `\exp_not:N`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_output_stream

\iow_open:Nn \g_output_stream { \c_sys_jobname_str.sbj }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nn \g_output_stream { \TeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:N \LaTeX{} }
\iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:N \TeX{} }
\iow_close:N \g_output_stream

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The auxiliary file will have

```latex
\LaTeX {}
\TeX {}
\LaTeX {}
\TeX {}
```

What's the difference? In this case `\exp_not:V` does a one step expansion, which is not desired here, because `\LaTeX` and `\TeX` are not *variables*, but parameterless *functions*. Recall that `V` stands for *variable* and is used to get its value, not subject to further expansion.

Comment: I should have mentioned that what is written to the auxiliary file is in fact
(only) the replacement text (that may contain `\TeX`) of a *token list*. Hence,
if I'm right, `\exp_not:N` is useless in my use case: I asked [this new
question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490177/18401) in order to explain why and a bit further my aim.